# Failed to Autowired on freemaker TemplateMethodModelEx implementation

Tags: java, freemarker

I want to call custom java method from freemaker template. After searching I found that we can call java method by below code

```
<#assign utility = "com.curaspan.ome.satyatest.TemplateTest"?new() >

<p>Patient summary : ${utility()} </p>
```

And on java code I have to code like

```
public class TemplateTest implements TemplateMethodModelEx {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myservice;

    @Override
    public Object exec(List arg0) throws TemplateModelException {

        // Write own logic here
        return myservice.callMyMethod();
    }
}
```

Here it failed to Autowire MyService.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think freemarker can autowrite with Spring annotations, so what you do is not possible.

Also this is just creating a new instance via a default constructor

```
"com.curaspan.ome.satyatest.TemplateTest"?new() >
```

Maybe you can create this bean before and refer to it from freemarker instead of creating a new instance from within freemarker.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any  other way we can inject a template(which is reside on database) ? Like Let's say I have template A and I want to inject template B from database on line no 4 of template A.